# Why are British soldiers not trying to catch Jack Sparrow?

Tags: pirates-of-the-caribbean, dead-men-tell-no-tales

At the start of the *Dead Men Tell No Tales (2017)*, Jack Sparrow stole a bank vault in front of British soldiers. Later, he is shown walking among British soldiers without fear and also British soldiers are not trying to catch him.

[image]

Why so?

Comment: Frank Hocken - I haven't seen dead-men-tell-no-tales.  Did Jack Sparrow really steal a bank vault or merely rob from the bank vault?

Comment: Frank is right, @M.A.Golding He actually stole a bank vault.

Comment: Sheedhar - I guess that's why the soldiers aren't chasing Jack in the scene.  They're looking for someone carrying a huge bank vault on his back!